How to resolve error in debug.log file
There are many hundreds of errors in the debug.log file:
[25-Dec-2024 14:21:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/mydomain.com/news/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173
How do I resolve this issue?
Please advise.

This is the PHP chmod() function, so likely this is a file permission issue. This function will only work if the files are owned by the same user that PHP is running under.

The owner "1003" is the same as all PHP files. How do I resolve this issue?
Please advise.

This question is similar to: PHP Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
